# The intersection of closure of span of infinite, linearly independent, closed, bounded, connected and disjoint subsets of $\ell^2$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two subsets of $\ell^2$ space over $\mathbb{C}$ such that each of them is: infinite, linearly independent, closed, bounded, connected and $X \cap Y = \emptyset$

I would like to know if is it true that 
$$
\overline{
\operatorname{span}
X
}
\cap
\overline{
\operatorname{span}
Y
}
=
\{0\}
$$

thanks.

Comment: What about $X = \{x\}$ and $Y = \{2x\}$ for some $x \neq 0$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Linear independence goes out the window.

Comment: ok @PhoemueX i understand, the answer is 'no', is it the same if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite?

Comment: I have no proof yet, but I think that $X$ and $Y$ can just contain one element since they are linearly independent and **connected**.

Comment: I have edited adding that $X$ and $Y$ are infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there exists an infinite, connected, closed, bounded and linearly independent set $X$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\}$, then you can define $Y=\{\alpha x~:~x\in X\}$. Then $Y$ is also infinite, connected, closed, bounded and linearly independent and $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ but 
$\overline{\operatorname{span}X}=\overline{\operatorname{span}Y}$.

So this argument work for $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb C$ and over $\mathbb R$.

But I suppose there cannot exist such a set. I am not sure, but somehow I think that a connected and linearly independent set cannot contain more than one element. But I have no proof yet.